# WPF - Implicitly style control within another control

Tags: wpf, styling, resourcedictionary

Is it possible in WPF to implictly style a control that sits within another control?

For example, style an image within a button, without styling all images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert the style into the ResourceDictionary of the Button. Then it only applies to contained images.